# $GL(n,K)$ is open in $M(n,K)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove, that $GL(n,K)$ is open in $M(n,K)$, where ($K=\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}\}$.

For the prove I don't want to use that the determinant is continous. Alternativly I assume a submultiplicative norm.

First step: Define $U_A:=\{B\in M(n,K):\Vert A-B\Vert<\frac{1}{\Vert A^{-1}\Vert}\}$ and show that it is a neighbourhod of $A$ in $M(n,K)$.

Second step: I show that the series $\sum_{k\ge0}(1-A^{-1}B)^kA^{-1}$ converges absolutely and the limit is inverse to $B$.

For the second step I should use the Neumann series, right? But I have some problems with the first step. Any help?

Comment: You could prove that a multiplicative group is open as soon as it has nonempty interior, and then check that $I$ is in the interior; that way you avoid a little bit of the mess.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $U_A = B_{\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}}(A)$, the open ball with centre $A$ and radius $\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$, so this is an open neighbourhood of $A$ essentially by the definition of the topology induced by a norm (a set is open if it is a union of balls $B_r(x) = \{y \;:\; \|x - y\| < r\}$).

Answer (score 1):

$GL(n,k)=det^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})$. $det:M(n,k)\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb R$.